# Find nearest value by group

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a practical way to retrieve the nearest value to `0` for each group using (preferably) `data.table`.

Assume the following `DT`:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(val = rnorm(1000), group = rep(1:10, each = 10)) # 10 groups
```

I have tried to combine both `by = group` and `roll = "nearest"`, but it only returns the nearest value *across* and not *by* groups:

```
DT[val == 0, val, by = group, roll = "nearest"]
#   group       value
#1:     8 0.001105352
```

I could of course repeat the process for each group, but it would be impractical as the number of groups increases. E.g.:

```
res <- rbind(DT[val == 0 & group = 1, val, by = group, roll = "nearest"],
             DT[val == 0 & group = 2, val, by = group, roll = "nearest"],
             DT[val == 0 & group = 3, val, by = group, roll = "nearest"],
             ...)
```

Maybe I am missing some `data.table` feature?

Comment: r u looking for `DT[.(group=1L:10L, val=0), .(x.group, x.val), on=.(group, val), roll = "nearest"]`?

Comment: A more generalised way of @chinsoon12's method: `DT[CJ(group = group, val = 0, unique = TRUE), on = .(group, val), .(group, x.val), roll = "nearest"]`

Comment: Fyi, roll = does nothing in your code above -- it only takes effect when `i` of `DT[i, ...]` is a list or data.table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a join for that.

A possible solution using a combination of `min` and `abs`:

```
DT[, .(closest.val.to.zero = val[abs(val) == min(abs(val))]), by = group]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     group closest.val.to.zero
>  1:     1         0.011292688
>  2:     2        -0.016190263
>  3:     3         0.002131860
>  4:     4         0.004398704
>  5:     5         0.017395620
>  6:     6         0.002415809
>  7:     7         0.004884450
>  8:     8         0.001105352
>  9:     9        -0.040150452
> 10:    10        -0.010925691
> ```

---

A more generalised way of the option as [posted by @chinsoon12 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363840/find-nearest-value-by-group#comment91671878_52363840):

```
DT[CJ(group = group, val = 0, unique = TRUE)
   , on = .(group, val)
   , .(group, closest.val.to.zero = x.val)
   , roll = "nearest"]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for the more generalised approach.